# Tkinter image with alpha channel works as desired in windows but not linux

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL and Numpy to add alpha channel to an image before displaying it in Tkinter GUI. I first read the image, convert it to "RGBA", convert it to array, add the alpha channel, convert back to image, display in Tkinter GUI.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as NP
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

image = PIL.Image.open('A.png')
image = image.convert('RGBA')
Arr=NP.array(image)
#apply alpha of 100
Arr[..., 3] = 100
TKimg=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.fromarray(Arr))
Label(root, image=TKimg,background='white').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB20F.png) I got when running the code on windows and linux.

The original image has a white background. After adding alpha in windows it is still has the white background "which I want". However, in linus the white background is destroyed.

So how to apply alpha and keep the white background in linux
Is there any method to achieve this using python

Thanks